# Update multiple rows with wildcards

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, wildcard

Can I do something like the following in Postgresql? Obviously the syntax in the second line is wrong.

```
UPDATE "MySchema"."MyTable"
SET email = '%@@%'
WHERE email LIKE '%@%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not work with wildcards like this, but you can use [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to do pretty much any string manipulation that you want. Doubling the `@` in an email address would go like this:

```
UPDATE "MySchema"."MyTable"
SET email = regexp_replace(email, '@', '@@')
WHERE email LIKE '%@%';
```

Comment: Okay great. I suppose I don't even need the third line, now that I think about it.

Comment: That line is not strictly necessary but it is an optimization where only a few rows would be updated. Every UPDATE is in fact a DELETE and an INSERT at the physical level so filtering out to UPDATE only where strictly necessary saves a lot of I/O.